# Ionic 3 feature module with multiple pages

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3

I am using Ionic 3 and angular 5. I have one feature module 'Settings':

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SettingsPage } from './test';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SettingsPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(SettingsPage),
  ],
})
export class SettingsPageModule {}
```

Under Settings module I want to add 5 more pages. 
I checked a lot of post and cannot found out how to do that. Is it even possible ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "Under"? Usually in Ionic 3, each page has its own directory containing 4 files, e.g. if the page is called SettingsPage, the dir will be src/pages/settings and inside you'll have: settings.html, settings.module.ts, settings.scss, settings.ts. Further pages should live "side by side", that is, use directories inside src/pages; to create the right structure I just use the `ionic generate` command - see https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/generate/

Comment: Sorry for misunderstandings, 'under' means 'in' module. Yes I know how ionic CLI works. I am going to have maybe 50-100 pages, and I want to separate them by folders and modules (like we do in standard angular app). I want 5 modules with 10-20 pages.

Answer (score 2):

The Ionic3 standard way, if you use lazy loading, is: one module per page.

If you use the CLI, `ionic generate page` command will do the job for you and create a folder with 4 files whenever you create a new page.

If you don't want pages to live each in a separate directory, one way could be to create the new page-related files in the same directory.

But, if you want **multiple pages** in one module, it's ***not going to work***, at least in my experience - e.g. if you try to place two pages in the same directory and load them from the same module, you'll get this error message:

> Error: /.../src/pages/pagegroup/pageX.ts has a @IonicPage decorator, but it does not have a corresponding "NgModule" at /.../src/pages/pagegroup/pageX.module.ts

Below I'm explaining a working solution to have **multiple pages**, each with its own module, in a **single directory**.

Let's assume you start from this:

```
src
  settings
    settings.html
    settings.module.ts
    settings.scss
    settings.ts
```

...and you want to add a page named "**CustomSettingsPage**".

Depending on how complex this page is, you must add the following 2 to 4 files, in the same directory (src/settings) - the optional ones are between square braces:

```
[custom-settings.html]
custom-settings.module.ts
[custom-settings.scss]
custom-settings.ts
```

The module and page .ts files will have a similar structure:

**custom-settings.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { CustomSettingsPage } from './custom-settings';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CustomSettingsPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(CustomSettingsPage),
  ],
  exports: [
    CustomSettingsPage
  ]
})
export class CustomSettingsPageModule {}
```

**custom-settings.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-custom-settings',
  template: `<your html template here>`
})
export class CustomSettingsPage {
   // your page code here
};
```

Instead of `template:` you could use `templateURL: 'custom-settings.html'` - in that case, you should create the corresponding `custom-settings.html` template file in the same directory.

If you want to add the CSS rules for this page, you can create an optional `custom-settings.scss` file like:

```
.page-custom-settings {
   /* your rules here */
}
```

or, you can add those CSS rules to the existing `settings.scss` file: this is really up to you.

Comment: This also required another module. My question was how to gather pages in one module. Or maybe this is even better way. But is it possible to import "CustomSettingsPageModule" to "CustomSettingsPage " and gather all settings page modules into one main settings module ?

Comment: @Milos AFAIK it's not feasible, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is "modals"

https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#modals

You can add individual pages under your settings.

Comment: Modal should not be used as a page. I need real page here. If you have some idea with code, you can expand your answer.

Comment: Sorry, but i am unable to understand your requirements!
I guessed, the use of modals from your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to this question but just in case someone needs it in the future!

I'm not sure if you are referring to this but you can have several pages into one module having a folder tree like, for example:

- pages

  - settings

    - childPage 1

      - child1.page.(html|scss|ts)
    - childPage 1

      - child1.page.(html|scss|ts)
    - settings.module.ts
    - settings.page.(html|scss|ts)

then in your Setting Routing Module you do like

```
import ...

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: 'pathtoRedirect', // if you need it
  pathMatch: 'full'
}, {
  path: '',
  component: SettingsPage
}, {
  path: 'child-page-1',
  component: ChildPage1
}, {
  path: 'child-page-2',
  component: ChildPage2
}]


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SettingsPageModule {}
```

Then in your App Routing Module you can do something like:

```
import ...

const routes: Routes = [{
...
}, {
  path: 'settings',
  loadChildren: () => import('./pages/settings/settings.module').then(m => m.SettingsPageModule),
}, {
  ...
}]


@NgModule({
 ...
})
export class AppRoutingModule{}
```

This should work. What a component needs is for it to be in ANY module. It's true "module per page strategy" is included as best practice, however, sometimes I simply don't want to have many files that actually can be deleted and managed under the same module.

From this point, you can have a different folder tree if you feel like it, or even create a deeper nested route like

- /settings
- /settings/children/:id
- /settings/children/otherchildren/childrenpage

Now it would be up to you and your project needs!

Hope this is useful for somebody!